# For Two Subsets Of A Vector Space $V$ which among the given option is correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $S =\{ x_1,x_2,x_3\ldots,x_m\}$ and $T = \{y_1,y_2,y_3\ldots y_n\}$ be subsets of a Vector space $V$

Then

(a) If $S$ and $T$ are both Linearly Independent Then $m  =n$

(b) If $S$ is a basis of $V$ and $T$ spans $V$ THEN $m \ge n$

(c) If $S$ is a basis for $V$ and if $T$ IS Linearly Independent then $m \ge n$

(d) If S is L.I. and if T spans $V$ then $m \le n$

I have proved that option (a)  and (b) are False

Now since basis is the maximal Linearly Independent Set hence option (c) must be correct.

But I am confused about option (d)

Can someone please tell me whether option (d) is False or True

Thank You.

Comment: Note that a basis is not only a maximal linearly independent set but also a minimal spanning set.

Comment: @Rick So, (d) is a correct option ?

Comment: Yes. You can now see the answer given. Hope I was of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$d$ is true since $T$ spans $V$ , $T$ spans $S$ thus it has at least as many elements as the linearly independent elements of $S$